# PHP get days between start-date and end-date

Tags: php, date, datediff

If I have two variables `$startDate="YYYYmmdd"` and `$endDate="YYYYmmdd"`, how can I get the number of days between them please?

Thank you.

Comment: please indicate if you want number of days inclusive or exclusive of the two dates.

Comment: Including the start and end, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using PHP 5.3, you can use the new [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class:

```
$startDate = new DateTime("20101013");
$endDate = new DateTime("20101225");

$interval = $startDate->diff($endDate);

echo $interval->days . " until Christmas"; // echos 73 days until Christmas
```

If not, you will need to use [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$startDate = strtotime("20101013");
$endDate = strtotime("20101225");

$interval = $endDate - $startDate;
$days = floor($interval / (60 * 60 * 24));

echo $days . " until Christmas"; // echos 73 days until Christmas
```

Comment: The new DateTime, DateTimeInterval, DateTimePeriod and DateTimeZone-classes just rock. I also made some experience with them. I think it's better than strtotime, because it considers leap-years, leap-seconts, etc. So +1 for you. I also gave an more detailed example in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108591/calculate-number-of-hours-between-2-dates-in-php/3108800#3108800

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php   
 $time1=strtotime($startDate);
    $time2=strtotime($endDate);
    $daycount=floor(($time2-$time1)/ 86400);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
function days($date1, $date2) {
    $date1 = strtotime($date1);
    $date2 = strtotime($date2);
    return ($date2 - $date1) / (24 * 60 * 60);
}
$date1 = '20100820';
$date2 = '20100930';
echo days($date1, $date2);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$DayDiff = strtotime("2010-01-12")-strtotime("2009-12-30");
echo  date('z', $DayDiff)." Days";
```

this one should be precise and usable with PHP < 5.2

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code

```
$startDate = mktime(0,0,0,1,1,2010); 
$endDate = mktime(0,0,0,12,1,2010); 

$dateDiff = $date1 - $date2;
$fullDays = floor($dateDiff/(60*60*24));
echo "Differernce is $fullDays days";
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I have found to get the number of days between them is by converting the Start and End dates to Unix timestamps and doing an subtract on them.

Then if you want to format the date convert it back using the PHP date function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach, based upon a brutal search in most cases, just because divisions by seconds (for weeks, months, years) may not return precise results, as while working with leap years for example.

```
<?php
function datediff( $timeformat, $startdate, $enddate )
{
    $unix_startdate = strtotime( $startdate ) ;
    $unix_enddate = strtotime( $enddate ) ;
    $min_date = min($unix_startdate, $unix_enddate);
    $max_date = max($unix_startdate, $unix_enddate);
    $Sd = date( "d", $unix_startdate ) ;
    $Sm = date( "m", $unix_startdate ) ;
    $Sy = date( "Y", $unix_startdate ) ;
    $Ed = date( "d", $unix_enddate ) ;
    $Em = date( "m", $unix_enddate ) ;
    $Ey = date( "Y", $unix_enddate ) ;

    $unixtimediff = $unix_enddate - $unix_startdate ;
    if ( $unixtimediff <= 0 ) return -1 ;

    switch( strtolower( $timeformat ) )
    {
         case "d": // days
         $divisor = 3600 * 24 ;
         return floor( $unixtimediff / $divisor ) + 1 ; 
         break ;
         case "w": // weeks
         $i = 0 ;
         while ( ( $min_date = strtotime("+1 DAY", $min_date) ) <= $max_date) $i++;
         return floor( $i / 7 ) ;
         break ;
         case "m": // months
         $i = $Sd != $Ed && $Sm != $Em ? 1 : 0 ;
         while ( ( $min_date = strtotime("+1 MONTH", $min_date) ) <= $max_date) $i++;
         return $i ;
         break ;
         case "q": // quaterly (3 months)
         $i = $Sd != $Ed && $Sm != $Em ? 1 : 0 ;
         while ( ( $min_date = strtotime("+3 MONTH", $min_date) ) <= $max_date) $i++;
         return $i ;
         break ;
         case "y": // year
         $i = $Sd != $Ed && $Sm != $Em ? 1 : 0 ;
         while ( ( $min_date = strtotime("+1 MONTH", $min_date) ) <= $max_date) $i++;
         return floor( $i / 12 ) ;
         break ;
    }
}

$startdate = "2014-01-01" ;
$enddate = "2015-12-31" ;
$formats = array( "d" => "days", "w" => "weeks", "m" => "months", "q" => "quaterly", "y" => "years" ) ;
foreach( $formats AS $K => $F )
echo "From $startdate to $enddate in $F format: ". datediff( "$K",  $startdate, $enddate )."<br>" ;
```

?>