# Calculate Number of Hours between 2 Dates - Excluding Weekends

Tags: php, datetime, date

Using this code: [Calculate number of hours between 2 dates in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108591/calculate-number-of-hours-between-2-dates-in-php) I want to calculate the number of hours between 2 timestamps.

What I need now is to be able to exclude weekend hours from this count?

e.g. For the following 2 time stamps, I'd expect the number of Hours to be 24 instead of 72.

```
$datetime1 = "2012-07-20 12:00:00";
$datetime2 = "2012-07-23 12:00:00";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code below should work. I'm assuming $datetime1 is always less than $datetime2.

```
$datetime1 = "2012-07-20 12:00:00"; 
$datetime2 = "2012-07-23 12:00:00";

$timestamp1 = strtotime($datetime1);
$timestamp2 = strtotime($datetime2);

$weekend = array(0, 6);

if(in_array(date("w", $timestamp1), $weekend) || in_array(date("w", $timestamp2), $weekend))
{
    //one of the dates is weekend, return 0?
    return 0;
}

$diff = $timestamp2 - $timestamp1;
$one_day = 60 * 60 * 24; //number of seconds in the day

if($diff < $one_day)
{
    return floor($diff / 3600);
}

$days_between = floor($diff / $one_day);
$remove_days  = 0;

for($i = 1; $i <= $days_between; $i++)
{
   $next_day = $timestamp1 + ($i * $one_day);
   if(in_array(date("w", $next_day), $weekend))
   {
      $remove_days++; 
   }
}

return floor(($diff - ($remove_days * $one_day)) / 3600);
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. When I use my example it returns 0. If I change date1 to 19/7/12 then the end value becomes 960

Comment: hey sorry, there was a small bug in the code. it should work fine now.

Comment: @KasiaGogolek i know this is old but can you please update the code supporting date1 or date2 is weekend date? because if my date1 is sunday then date2 is wednesday. it doesnt get the right hours