# Difference of hours between two dates (integer)

Tags: php, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate number of hours between 2 dates in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108591/calculate-number-of-hours-between-2-dates-in-php)

How can I get the number of hours of difference between two dates in PHP?  I need to get an integer since I want to know if is bigger or smaller than a particular value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$time1 = time();
$time2 = mktime(0,0,0,11,13,2012); // earlier today
echo ($time1 - $time2) / 3600; // 3600 seconds in hour
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
 $date1 = "2012-11-05 12:35:00";
 $date2 = "2012-11-07 14:35:00"; 
 $diff = strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1);
 $diff_in_hrs = $diff/3600;
 print_r($diff_in_hrs);
```

[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

[Demo](http://codepad.org/1hkztJV7)

Answer (score 2):

If you have an up-to-date PHP

```
$dateOne = new DateTime('2012-01-20 00:00:00');
$dateTwo = new DateTime('2012-01-21 02:00:00');
```

// Procedurally
    $interval = date_diff($dateOne, $dateTwo);

```
// Alternatively OOP style if supported
$interval = $dateOne->diff($dateTwo);
```

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Comment: You'll get `undefined function date_diff` or `unknown method diff` if it's not up to date. Or just check `php -v` / `phpinfo()`

Comment: you will recieve a Fatal error if you do not set the default timezone (`date_default_timezone_set()`)

Comment: You set that in your php.ini `date.timezone = 'Europe/London';` or using `date_default_timezone_set()` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php