# count hours remain between 2 dates with php

Tags: php, date, strtotime

i have this dates

```
$dt_occ     = mysql_result($info,0,"occ_data");
$dt_occ     = strtotime($dt_occ);
$dt_occ     = strtotime('+1 day' , $dt_occ);
$dt_unico   = date('d/m/Y H:i',$dt_occ);
$dt_il      = date('d/m/Y',$dt_occ);
$dt_alle    = date('H:i',$dt_occ);
```

I need to know how many hours remain between now and $dt_unico

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate number of hours between 2 dates in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108591/calculate-number-of-hours-between-2-dates-in-php)

Comment: What does var_dump($dt_occ) give after your first line of code?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) classes, they are much more flexible that strtotime() and date() (IMHO). Something like this will work for you:-

```
function getDiffInHours(\DateTime $earlierDate, \DateTime $laterDate)
{
    $utc = new \DateTimeZone('UTC');
    //Avoid side effects
    $first = clone $earlierDate;
    $second = clone $laterDate;
    //First convert to UTC to avoid missing hours due to DST etc
    $first->setTimezone($utc);
    $second->setTimezone($utc);
    $diff = $first->diff($second);
    return 24 * $diff->days + $diff->h;
}
```

Use it like this for example:-

```
$hours = getDiffInHours(new \DateTime($dt_occ), (new \DateTime($dt_occ))->modify('+ 1 day'));
var_dump($hours); //24
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you.

```
$dt1 = new DateTime($dt_occ);
$dt2 = new DateTime($dt_occ);
$dt2->modify("+1 day");
$interval = $dt2->diff($dt1);
echo $interval->hours;
```

If you're using PHP5.5 you can simply this a little bit:

```
$dt1 = new DateTimeImmutable($dt_occ);
$dt2 = $dt1->modify("+1 day");
$interval = $dt2->diff($dt1);
echo $interval->hours;
```

Comment: However, this will give odd results for intervals > 24 hours. Also it should be echo $interval->h; http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Comment: Also DateTime::sub takes a DateInterval as a parameter, not a DateTime. you are looking for DateTime::diff().

Comment: DateInterval object doesn't have `hours` property.

Answer (score 0):

Since `$dt_unico` is derived from `$dt_occ`, which is a timestamp and `time()` gives the current time, also as a timestamp, subtracting the former from the latter will give the interval between them, in seconds.

Now, an hour is `60*60=3600` seconds, so:

```
$interval=(time()-$dt_occ)/3600;
```

Some notes, though:

- I assumed that `$dt_occ` refers to the past. Future dates will give negative results, so if that's the case, switch the subtraction operands.
- The above will give a floating point result. For an integral result, use the appropriate rounding function depending on the desired rounding method.

Comment: If there is a DST change between the two times this will give an incorrect result by +/- 1 hour.

Comment: @vascowhite No it won't. `time()` will be converted to the correct timestamp, while `$dt_occ` is a timestamp already.