# PHP - Comparing date, checking if within last hour

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm attempting to see if a time is within the last hour.

```
$unit_date = date($unit['last_accessed'], 'Y-m-d H:i:s');

$last_hour = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 hour')); 

if($unit_date >= $last_hour ){
    $connect = "<i class='fa fa-circle 2x' style='color:#2ECC71;'></i>";
} else {
    $connect = '';
}
```

As you can see I'm putting $unit['last_accessed'] into the correct format then comparing to an hour ago. If the time is within the last hour $connect is a font awesome circle (colored green), if it's not within the last hour it's empty, right now it's saying nothing is within the last hour which is false.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
if(time() - strtotime($unit['last_accessed']) < 3601){
```

or

```
if(time() - strtotime($unit['last_accessed']) > 3599){
```

time() and strtotime() both use the same time base in seconds

if $unit['last_accessed'] is already an integer time variable then do not use strtotime().

Comment: Simple, and much less complex then what I had. Thank you.

Comment: I did not know if $unit['last_accessed'] is a string or time variable.

Answer (score 3):

**DateTime** solution

```
$firstDate = new \DateTime('2019-10-16 07:00:00');
$secondDate = new \DateTime('2019-10-17 07:00:00');

$diff = $firstDate->diff($secondDate);
$diffHours = $diff->h;

// diff in hours (don't worry about different years, it's taken into account)
$diffInHours = $diffHours + ($diff->days * 24);

// more than 1 hour diff
var_dump($diffInHours >= 1);
```

Origin similar answer: [Calculate number of hours between 2 dates in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108591/calculate-number-of-hours-between-2-dates-in-php/3108800#3108800)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you're using date function in a wrong way. From PHP's manual:

```
date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )
```

You must provide as first argument the $format string and the $timestamp as the second. You can check if the time is whitin the last hour without transform the Unix Timestamp to a another timestamp string.

```
$last_hour = time() - 60*60; //last hour timestamp
if($unit['last_accessed'] >= $last_hour){
       $connect = "<i class='fa fa-circle 2x' style='color:#2ECC71;'></i>";
}else{
       $connect = '';
}
```

As you can see, i didnt made any transformation to the timestamp, as i'm not using the timestring in anywhere. You should learn a little more about operations with unix timestamp's or about php time functions.

**References:**
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Agreed, a little confusion. Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an error in your code.  In one place you call `date` like this:

> date(*format*, *time*)

and in another place, like this:

> date(*time*, *format*)

Check the PHP documentation for `date` and figure out which one is correct.  Otherwise your code looks logically correct, if perhaps needlessly complex.