# Show PHP time as hours greater than 24 hrs like 70 hrs

Tags: php, mysql, time

I have below code which shows time

```
$now = date_create(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

$replydue = date_create($listing['replydue_time']);

$timetoreply = date_diff($replydue, $now);

echo $timetoreply->format('%H:%I')
```

Byt my problem is if difference is more than 24 hrs, it breaks time in more 24 hrs and shows 1 or 2 or any hours but below 24 hrs.

How can i show real hours difference like 74 hrs!

Thanks,

Comment: You have to convert both into seconds and get difference in seconds. Then you should convert the difference from seconds to hours.

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes - You should but not have.

Comment: Thnx @KanchoIliev, my bad :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate number of hours between 2 dates in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108591/calculate-number-of-hours-between-2-dates-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally I'd prefer the following approach.. rather than reinvent the wheel or do lots of manual conversions:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$replydue = new DateTime($listing['replydue_time']);

$timetoreply_hours = $timetoreply->days * 24 + $timetoreply->h;
echo $timetoreply_hours.':'.$timetoreply->format('%I');
```

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php):

> days: If the DateInterval object was created by DateTime::diff(), then this is the total number of days between the start and end dates. Otherwise, days will be FALSE.

**Please note this assumes that all days are 24hrs which may not be the case in areas with DST**

I have written the following function to assist with this:

```
/**
 * @param DateTimeInterface $a
 * @param DateTimeInterface $b
 * @param bool              $absolute Should the interval be forced to be positive?
 * @param string            $cap The greatest time unit to allow
 * 
 * @return DateInterval The difference as a time only interval
 */
function time_diff(DateTimeInterface $a, DateTimeInterface $b, $absolute=false, $cap='H'){
  // Get unix timestamps
  $b_raw = intval($b->format("U"));
  $a_raw = intval($a->format("U"));

  // Initial Interval properties
  $h = 0;
  $m = 0;
  $invert = 0;

  // Is interval negative?
  if(!$absolute && $b_raw<$a_raw){
    $invert = 1;
  }

  // Working diff, reduced as larger time units are calculated
  $working = abs($b_raw-$a_raw);

  // If capped at hours, calc and remove hours, cap at minutes
  if($cap == 'H') {
    $h = intval($working/3600);
    $working -= $h * 3600;
    $cap = 'M';
  }

  // If capped at minutes, calc and remove minutes
  if($cap == 'M') {
    $m = intval($working/60);
    $working -= $m * 60;
  }

  // Seconds remain
  $s = $working;

  // Build interval and invert if necessary
  $interval = new DateInterval('PT'.$h.'H'.$m.'M'.$s.'S');
  $interval->invert=$invert;

  return $interval;
}
```

This can be used:

```
$timetoreply = time_diff($replydue, $now);
echo $timetoreply->format('%r%H:%I');
```

**N.B.** I have used `format('U')` instead of `getTimestamp()` because of the comment in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php).

Also not that 64-bit is required for post-epoch and pre-negative-epoch dates!

Comment: are you sure this is correct? $timetoreply->days * 24 because if i go with this i can strange numbers of hours, and if i go with $interval->format('%a')*24, i get correct hours.

Comment: hmm Perfect! Got it now and converted!

Comment: Does this means convert both to UNIX time then subtract, as given in below post by William Francis?

Comment: @rjcode It sure does.. but I like to use the PHP objects if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code:

```
<?php
$date1 = "2014-05-27 01:00:00";
$date2 = "2014-05-28 02:00:00";
$timestamp1 = strtotime($date1);
$timestamp2 = strtotime($date2);
echo "Difference between two dates is " . $hour = abs($timestamp2 - $timestamp1)/(60*60) . " hour(s)";
?>
```

Try to follow above process. If you need any help i will be glad to assist.

Hope it will work.

Source: [How to Calculate Hours Between Two Dates in PHP](http://schoolsofweb.com/how-to-calculate-hours-between-two-dates-in-php/)

Answer (score 1):

I'll offer this one solution, in case you like it in hours:

```
echo $interval->format('%a')*24+$interval->format('%h');
```

regarding the note below - it can be in this way too:

```
echo $interval->days*24 + $interval->h;
```

Comment: I was going to upvote this.. but there are properties in the DateInterval class that allow you to access these numbers without using the format function.

Comment: It's truth, but shown on this way I think the idea is much clear

Comment: How is it clearer, you are using a two character string to prompt conversion from an interval into a string. Then implicitly convert those into numbers, do a calculation and change it back to a string.. You honestly think that `format('%a')` is clearer than `days`?

Comment: Thanks :) But I have some logic behind, when I used 'a' but It probably will be hard for my bad English. I liked to use 'a' with idea that it is not directly associates by days. There are d and D too, but they are similar like a h - returns up to 31 days ( like a 'h' - up to 24 ). That's way I used 'a'.  If I've used ->days, the direct association will not clear the question if it is limited to 31. That was my logic - may be a bit strange but ... Fo rest you @Arth are quite right.

Comment: Good point.. I agree it is a bit confusing. I'd rather clear that up with a comment than using a round-about method with an obscure parameter however!

Answer (score 0):

The below code will output the difference in hours between any two days. In this case, 72. Hope this helps!

```
<?php

$startTime = new \DateTime('now');
$endTime = new \DateTime('+3 day');
$differenceInHours = round((strtotime($startTime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")) - strtotime($endTime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")))/3600, 1);
echo $differenceInHours;
```