# Fatal error on DateTime::diff on string

Tags: php, datetime, google-calendar-api

I ask here well knowing that there is other questions and answers on this and i have been going through them:
[Calculate number of hours between 2 dates in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108591/calculate-number-of-hours-between-2-dates-in-php)

But i still can't find a solution to my problem.
Here is the scenario:
Im using the Google Calendar Api. I have a `foreach()` loop running, where it graps the `dateTime()` for the event.
I want to get the differens from the start and end time. My code is as follows:

```
$neweventDateStr = new DateTime($event->start->dateTime);
$neweventDateEnd = new DateTime($event->end->dateTime);
$diff = $eventDateEnd->diff($neweventDateStr);
```

However i get the following error on the last line:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function diff() on string
```

I have checked and both variables are recognised as dateTime Objects.
Therefore i can't figure out why is giving me the error as listed above.
Any clue as to why this is?

Note, the code:

```
$event->start->dateTime
```

Returns the value of the date and time from the google server as a dateTime RFC 3339 format: source:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events

It returns the values like so:

```
$event->start->dateTime = 2015-07-06T14:30:00+02:00 
$event->se->dateTime = 2015-07-06T15:30:00+02:00
```

I have tried to:

```
echo $neweventDateStr;
```

and i returns the error(as expected) that the variable couldn't be turned into a string since its a `dateTime` Object format.

Comment: Post the values of `$event->start->dateTime` and `$event->end->dateTime` too

Comment: @DJESMOND i have added an explanation.check that.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your code:-

```
     $diff = $eventDateEnd->diff($neweventDateStr);
```

it should be :-

```
$diff = $neweventDateEnd->diff($neweventDateStr); // because no where $eventDateEnd is defined.
```

An example is as follows:-

```
<?php
 $neweventDateStr = new DateTime('2015-04-04 10:10:10');
 $neweventDateEnd = new DateTime('2015-04-10 10:10:10');
 $diff = $neweventDateEnd->diff($neweventDateStr); // instead of $eventDateEnd i write $neweventDateEnd
 print_r($diff);
 ?>
```

Output:-https://eval.in/393320

Comment: Jesus im blind.... i have been sitting here going it over and over for 5 hours.... Im so sorry