# Calculate Number of hours worked in 2 24 hour time format PHP

Tags: php, time

Hi I have a two variable in 24 hour time format and want to compute the number of hours worked. But I get negative and wrong value

I'm using PHP and here's my code

```
$endtime = date( 'g:i A', strtotime( $itInfo['endTime'] ) );
$startTime = date( 'g:i A', strtotime( $itInfo['startTime'] ) );
$timeDiff = (strtotime($endtime) - strtotime($startTime))/60/60;
$total      = strtotime($endtime) - strtotime($startTime);
$hours      = floor($total / 60 / 60);
$minutes    = round(($total - ($hours * 60 * 60)) / 60);

echo "FROM ".$itInfo['startTime']." TO ".$itInfo['endTime']." (".$hours.'.'.$minutes."hours)";`
```

Here's the output FROM 22:00 TO 03:00 (-19.0hours) which is wrong the output should be 5 Hours.

Comment: do you have time in this format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate number of hours between 2 dates in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108591/calculate-number-of-hours-between-2-dates-in-php)

Comment: No. I'm saving it as varchar with this format HH:MM in 24 hours

Comment: You really should work with timestamps (`time();`) internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$timeDiff = strtotime($itInfo['endTime']) - strtotime($itInfo['startTime']);

echo substr('00'.($timeDiff / 3600 % 24),-2)
    .':'. substr('00'.($timeDiff / 60 % 60),-2)
    .':'. substr('00'.($timeDiff % 60),-2);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, best to work with timestamps. But with your current code, you should be able to add this right before the `echo`:

```
if ($itInfo['startTime'] > $itInfo['endTime']) {
    $hours = 24 - $hours;
}
```

This would be: `24 - 19 = 5`.

Also, be sure to take add `abs()` in your `$total` variable as well:

`$total = abs(strtotime($endtime) - strtotime($startTime));`

Comment: Don't use `abs()`, as that will mask potential errors from faulty input-values ...

Comment: Interesting point, thanks! Can you give an example of how so?

Comment: If the calculated difference comes out negative (which should NEVER happen), `abs()` will make it positive ... and you may have a hard time figuring out, what went wrong.