# How to find the number of hours between two days?

Tags: php, datetime

So I have an array of many images in it with their datetimes in the format `Y-m-d H:i:s` And I wish to find the number of days between the image's date and the current date. This is where I have reached till now...and I'm getting a new error for every small change I make.

```
$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $current_time);
$currentDate = $myDateTime->format('Y-m-d');

foreach($all_images as $key => $am){

        $myDateTime1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $am['datetime']);
        $imageDate = $myDateTime1->format('Y-m-d');

        $datediff=date_diff($currentDate,$imageDate);
        echo $datediff;
}
```

I'm getting this error:
`Warning: date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given`

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Usually if you deal with date calculations it's easiest to convert both dates into seconds-since-epoch and then just compare them.

Comment: Or you could just subtract your two timestamps and divide the result by 3600.

Comment: @Jerodev I did do that but then I'm getting zero

Comment: @neuhaus, how can I do that? Like which functions should I use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108591/calculate-number-of-hours-between-2-dates-in-php

Comment: @KlaraNewbie use the mktime function

Comment: @neuhaus I *think* that is bad advice and I would suggest using the [DateTime object](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) rather than the older procedural `mktime` approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate number of hours between 2 dates in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108591/calculate-number-of-hours-between-2-dates-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done is you've converted your values to `Strings` before comparing them, so it's no longer comparing the difference between two dates but instead the difference between two strings. This is your error cause.

**Solution:**
The values you pass to `date_diff` need to be `two DateTime objects` as per the **manual:**

> (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0, PHP 7)
>   DateTime::diff -- DateTimeImmutable::diff -- DateTimeInterface::diff -- date_diff — Returns the difference between two DateTime objects

**Suggestion:**

```
foreach($all_images as $key => $am){

        $myDateTime1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $am['datetime']);
        $imageDate = $myDateTime1->format('Y-m-d');

        $datediff=date_diff($myDateTime, $myDateTime1);
        echo $datediff->format('%R%a days'); // +2 days
}
```

Note that the above `date_diff` function takes *`Objects`* not `strings`.

This will now use `date_diff` [procedurally in this example] to output a difference value `$datediff` which you can use with [DateTime formatting](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) to reach the number of days/hours/whatever. Please [Read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).

Comment: Good good! I take it if you simply used the object rather than the `->format`ted version that fixed it?

Comment: Sure! :) Thanks again!