# Calculate php datetime and convert to hours

Tags: php, datetime, time, double, hour

I'd like to calculate the difference in **hours** between two datetimes elements, but I need to have the exact value of it (like a double variable).

How may I do it?

I have no code samples because I got really stucked in this case, I really need the exact hours of this datetime element and I think date_diff can't give this value in a precise way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate number of hours between 2 dates in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108591/calculate-number-of-hours-between-2-dates-in-php)

Comment: your input example and your output suggest please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems to look for the [getTimestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) method :

```
<?php

$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2016-02-10 07:00:00');
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2017-03-11 19:00:00');

$diff = diff_hours($date1, $date2);
var_dump($diff);
function diff_hours(DateTime $date1, DateTime $date2) {
    $diff = $date2->getTimestamp() - $date1->getTimestamp();
    return $diff / ( 60 * 60 );
}
```

Comment: this is the most accurate way to get the time in hours, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method.

```
$date1 = "2014-03-07 05:49:23";
$date2 = "2014-03-14 05:49:23";
$seconds = strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1);
$hours = $seconds / 60 /  60;
```