# How we can get difference of time In "H:i:s" time format as given scenario?

Tags: php, time

here is scenario that i have two time as given i have only time part of `datetime` in 24 hour format

```
$start_time = "23:00:00";
$end_time = "07:00:00";
```

How i can calculate duration hours , if the start_time's hour part is greater then $end_time's hour.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: @JustBaron i have tried but i want time from 23:00 hour started and end at 07:00

Comment: You'll need the date/full timestamp to define that the end time is on the "next day"

Comment: i don't have because this a general time shifting for users and i am storing only hours and minutes, can you please try to solve this as it is

Comment: Check out DeadMaster's answer

Comment: no dear @JustBaron because "24:00:00" is equal to 00:00:00 compiler of php read it as so still not solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just create an if, where if the start time is bigger you have to calculate 24h (base_time) minus the start time first.

```
$start_time = "23:00:00";
$end_time = "07:00:00";
$base_time = "24:00:00";

if ($start_time>$end_time) {
 $time = $base_time-$start_time+$end_time;
} else {
 $time = $start_time-$end_time;
}
```

Or you can also have a look **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108591/calculate-number-of-hours-between-2-dates-in-php)**, if you also have the day format given.

The way over DateTime, as far as I know, is just possible with a date. So you could add a pseudo date infront... and then use [diff](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.diff.php) :

```
$start_time = "23:00:00";
$end_time = "07:00:00";
$st = new DateTime("0000-00-00".$start_time);
$et = new DateTime("0000-00-01".$end_time);

$interval = $st->diff($et);
$time = $interval->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

Comment: no dear because `"24:00:00"` is equal to `00:00:00` compiler of php read it as so still not solved

Comment: @MudassarZahid Maybe if you use a pseudo date? I have updated the answer, so you can see what I mean.