# How to take first index and last index while using multidimensional array and foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here i am doing task allocation per employee wise, almost i completed i have to do Hours calculation in project wise

```
    <?php
include("dbconfig.php");
include("functions.php");
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT date_add(date(d_started_on), interval i day) as allocation_date,t_project,t_assign_to,t_start_time,t_end_time FROM ( SELECT date(STR_TO_DATE(t_started_on, '%Y-%m-%d')) as d_started_on, datediff( date(STR_TO_DATE(t_due_on, '%Y-%m-%d')), date(STR_TO_DATE(t_started_on, '%Y-%m-%d')) ) as days,t_project,t_assign_to,t_start_time,t_end_time FROM task ) as base INNER JOIN nums ON i <= days ORDER BY 1";
$mysql = mysql_query($sql);
$productsArray = array();
while($rowRes = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql)){
    $rowRes['allocated_day'] = $rowRes['allocation_date'];
    $productsArray[] = $rowRes;
}
$project_name = array();
foreach($productsArray as $key0 => $info) {
    $key1 = $info['t_assign_to'];
    $key2 = $info['t_project'];
    $key3 = $info['allocated_day'];
    $project_name[$key1][$key2][$key3] = $info['t_start_time'].' '.$info['t_end_time']; 
}

print_r($project_name);
?>
```

> OUTPUT

```
    Array
(
    [G2E0357] => Array
        (
            [10001] => Array
                (
                    [2018-01-01] => 01:30 PM 11:30 AM
                    [2018-01-02] => 01:30 PM 11:30 AM
                    [2018-01-03] => 01:30 PM 11:30 AM
                )

            [10008] => Array
                (
                    [2018-01-25] => 10:30 AM 01:30 PM
                    [2018-01-26] => 10:30 AM 01:30 PM
                    [2018-01-27] => 10:30 AM 01:30 PM
                )

        )

    [XPL0315] => Array
        (
            [10008] => Array
                (
                    [2018-01-18] => 11:30 AM 07:30 PM
                    [2018-01-19] => 11:30 AM 07:30 PM
                    [2018-01-20] => 11:30 AM 07:30 PM
                )

        )

)
```

1. **G2E0357** and **XPL0315** these are employee id's
2. **10001** and **10008** these are project id's
3. 2018-01-01(project start date ) 2018-01-03 (project end date)
4. 01:30 PM(start time) 11:30 AM(end time)

> Explnation

employee id **XPL0315** having one project allocation (**10008**) .timeline is `2018-01-18`  11:30 AM  INTO `2018-01-20` 07:30 PM,

Instead of displaying **t_start_time** and **t_end_time**. i have to calculate per day how many Hours employee has to work

> My Office timing is 9.30 AM into 7.30 PM (Totally 10 Hrs)

employee id **XPL0315** and project id **10008** having 3 days allocation but working hours it will be different based allocation ,because

1. 2018-01-18 date he is going to start 11.30 PM(7 Hrs Only)
2. 2018-01-19 employee has to start the work 9.30 AM into 7.30 PM because allocation ending date 2018-01-18 07:30 PM (10 Hrs)
3. 2018-01-20 also employee has to start the work 9.30 AM into 7.30 PM because allocation ending date 2018-01-18 07:30 PM (10 Hrs) suppose **ending date is 2018-01-20 06:30 PM (9 Hrs)**

> Expected output should come like this

```
    Array
(
    [G2E0357] => Array
        (
            [10001] => Array
                (
                    [2018-01-01] => 6 Hrs
                    [2018-01-02] => 10 Hrs
                    [2018-01-03] => 2 Hrs
                )

            [10008] => Array
                (
                    [2018-01-25] => 9 Hrs
                    [2018-01-26] => 10 Hrs
                    [2018-01-27] => 4 Hrs
                )

        )

    [XPL0315] => Array
        (
            [10008] => Array
                (
                    [2018-01-18] => 7 Hrs
                    [2018-01-19] => 10 Hrs
                    [2018-01-20] => 10 Hrs
                )

        )

)
```

**I think we have to take first index and last index**,

1. first index means we have to take **t_start_time** and do the
   calculation
2. last index means we have to take **t_end_time** and do the
   calculation

Comment: I've read the entire thing, and I'm not sure what your question is. Also, please reserve quoteblocks for quotes, that's what they're for; instead, use headings

Comment: You want the number of hours between your time strings?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108591/calculate-number-of-hours-between-2-dates-in-php

Comment: Hello all ,in my case project id `10001` having 3 days allocation`2018-01-01 01:30 PM` into `2018-01-03 11:30 AM`, in this allocation i want to know per day how may hrs , i have work ? for that 1st day he should start work on 1:30 PM upto 7:30 Pm bcz my office timing already i given so first day (`1:30 PM into 7:30PM = 6 Hrs`) second day (`9:30 AM into 7:30 PM= 10 Hrs`) third day (`9:30 AM into 11:30 PM= 2 Hrs`)

Comment: @William Perron,are you getting my question ?

Comment: @MithunM There is still no question statement in your post. Please narrow down our question to a **specific** problem you are having in a **clear** and **concise** way

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    $project_name = array();
    foreach($productsArray as $key0 => $info) {
        $key1 = $info['t_assign_to'];
        $key2 = $info['t_project'];
        $key3 = $info['allocated_day'];
    /* Add this code */
    $start = new DateTime(date("H:i:s", strtotime($info['t_start_time']))); //'10:35:20'
    $end = new DateTime(date("H:i:s", strtotime($info['t_end_time'])));//'02:00:45'

    $diff = $start->diff( $end );
    $hrs = $diff->format( '%H'.' Hrs'  ); //'%H:%I:%S' => 02:25:25

    $project_name[$key1][$key2][$key3] = $hrs;
   /* Add this code */
    }
```

Comment: Mr Prashant,i am not getting my expected results, i am getting **Array
 (
 [G2E0357] => Array
 (
 [10001] => Array
 (
 [2018-01-01] => 02 Hrs
 [2018-01-02] => 02 Hrs
 [2018-01-03] => 02 Hrs
 )

 [10008] => Array
 (
 [2018-01-25] => 03 Hrs
 [2018-01-26] => 03 Hrs
 [2018-01-27] => 03 Hrs
 )

 )

 [XPL0315] => Array
 (
 [10008] => Array
 (
 [2018-01-18] => 08 Hrs
 [2018-01-19] => 08 Hrs
 [2018-01-20] => 08 Hrs
 )

 )

 )**

Comment: Hello Prashant ,in my case project id `10001` having 3 days allocation `2018-01-01 01:30 PM` into `2018-01-03 11:30 AM`, in this allocation i want to know per day how many hrs , i have to work ? for that 1st day he should start work on 11:30 PM upto 7:30 PM` bcz my office timing already i given so first day (`1:30 PM into 7:30PM = 6 Hrs`) second day (`9:30 AM into 7:30 PM= 10 Hrs`) third day (`9:30 AM into 11:30 PM= 2 Hrs`)

Comment: I tried lot Mr Prashant,Please update my code, i am not able to do i spent so much time for this

Comment: time formate in DateTime($info['t_start_time']); should be H:i:s  data will be 11:00:00 then you will calculate perfect result,  this format is wrong 11:00 PM, i had already write in comment. you can see that

Comment: Task allocation time time format is `H:i:s A` i can't change this format , not possible to get the expected results from this format Mr @ Prashant

Comment: You telling 24 hrs format i have to make ?,can you please update your code include `print_r($project_name);`

Comment: To echo 16:30:00 from 4, 30 and PM,       echo date("H:i:s", strtotime("$hour:$minute $period"));

Comment: try this                                                                                                   $start = new DateTime( date("H:i:s", strtotime($info['t_start_time'])));
 $end = new DateTime( date("H:i:s", strtotime($info['t_end_time'])));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163740/discussion-between-prashant-and-mithun-m).